# Creating a new cpuset within a Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, cgroups, cpuset

I've launched a Kubernetes pod (single container) with a [static CPU management policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#static-policy). It has a CPU request/limit of 10. This all seems to be working as expected:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus
11-20
```

What I'd like to do now is reserve a couple of those cores for a couple very specific threads that are very sensitive to context-switching. Is it possible to create a child cpuset with just a couple of those CPUs? The `cgroup` filesystem is mounted as read-only:

```
mount | fgrep cpuset
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
```

…and so the usual procedure of using [`mkdir` to create child cpusets](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/cpusets.html#how-do-i-use-cpusets) doesn't work out of the box. I haven't found a way to mount `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/` as read-write.

My read between the lines is that this is all the intended behavior, and allowing pods to further subdivide their CPUs isn't supported. Still, is there a way to create a cpuset within a pod that I'm missing?